# What do we do with a Dead Link in a post?

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

It took me a bit to not start singing a shanty there...

[Ahem] So I came across an old question of mine, it is a *very* old question; to the point where it could be deleted and no one would notice. [Do cauldrons catch rainwater?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221358/do-cauldrons-catch-rainwater) [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), posted in 2016.

The question is fine, however the answer has a video link that has since been deleted. Again, the answer is also fine, capturing the information from the video in a quote; so again the answer is still valid.

However, now there's a big black "Video Unavailable" block covering half of the post. What should be done about this kind of thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the post holds valid without the video, I would say we could simply edit the post and remove it since it serves no purpose anymore. Normally I try to find archive links to replace them with, but in this case that isn't possible.

You could say the system works in this case.  Link-only answers are frowned upon for this very reason, so it's a good thing this post has supporting information to go along with the link.

Comment: Exactly. Saving this question for when a user is asking 'but why should I write what was on the site/in the video if it tells it all?